# Which tool with a square icon that has "Performance" and "Powersave" is this?

Tags: 20.04, tools

[image: The tool's icon is a black square with three small protrusions for each of the top and left sides, and a white bar across the bottom. Its menu has "Performance" and "Powersave" options, with a dot next to "Powersave".]

I installed this while looking for a tool for powersaving, referencing an answer here. But it is not serving the purpose. Which tool is this, and how can I remove it?

My Ubuntu version:

> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
> Release:    20.04
> Codename:   focal

Comment: Have you right-clicked on it?  That’s the first thing I do when wanting to know about something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This applet/indicator is named [`indicator-cpufreq`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=indicator-cpufreq&searchon=names):

> [image]

You can remove it by

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-cpufreq
```

Comment: Thanks! It this tool really worth adding to optimize power. I have recently dual booted ubuntu from windows. But the batttery life has sharlply decreased. In windows its generally 4-5 hrs but in ubuntu it's not even 2 hrs. CPU is heated everytime and fans are on all time. Tried installing indicator-cpufreq, tlp, screen brightness to minium etc but nothing is working. What should I do. I am using Lenovo L340 laptop.

Comment: If you have Nvidia graphics, make sure that it runs using proprietary closed-source video driver. Check in Software & Updates, on Drivers tab.

Comment: I have asked this question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383261/ubuntu-power-optimisation-problem-cpu-heated-everytime-fans-are-running-all-ti 

and added all relevant information needed. Please help me fixing the issue ! Thanks !