# Ubuntu Power Optimisation Problem. CPU Heated everytime, Fans are running all time

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, power-management, overheating

I have recently dual boot from windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.
My Laptop Specifications: Lenovo Ideapad L340, i7 9750H, Nvidia 1650 Graphics Card.

Problems: CPU is heated every time and fans are on all the time. The Battery life has decreased a lot. In windows, it's generally 4-5 hrs but in ubuntu, it's not even 2 hrs.

Tried Solutions Like screen brightness to minimum, installed tlp, indicator-cpufreq, switched GPU from Nvidia (on demand) to intel (power saving mode).

But nothing is working, I don't know I have installed too many packages and tools referring to many answers. In windows there is control pannel to see programs installed, but in ubuntu I don't know what things I have installed.

[image: Drivers]

[image: Nvdia Drivers]

I have attached the screenshots of drivers I have installed. I don't know where to check which packages are installed. In case this helps solving the problem, else I am thinking of factory reset.

**Edit1: Neofetch output (Hope this helps in suggesting some solution)**

[image: neofetch]

**Edit 2: Updating list of packages I have installed** `apt-mark showmanual`

[image: apt-mark showmanual]

Comment: You can run `apt list --installed` to view all the installed packages.

Comment: Also, In this case, `neofetch` is beneficial. Run `sudo apt install neofetch` and then [edit] your question to include the output of `neofetch`.

Comment: @someone: Much better than `apt list --installed` is `apt-mark showmanual` which gives a list of only the packages which were explicitly installed. On my system, the former gives 2812 packages and libs, the latter just 546.

Comment: @someone Updated Neofetch output in the answer. Please help !

Comment: @emk2203 Updated list of packages screenshot as you suggested. Hope this information helps suggesting some possible solutions. Thanks !

Comment: Use `top` and sort it by cpu time to find out which process is using your cpu. I think you will also find other tools to analyze power usage by process. Maybe you find a resource-hungry process that way.